# Delete subtree from ANTLR AST

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have an AST from an ANTLR grammar. I am using a `ParseTreeWalker` and the generated listener to walk through the nodes. My requirement is to delete few nodes and I was able to do it through a `TokenStreamRewriter`. Is it possible to delete a subtree similar to deleting tokens ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have your TreeWalker constructing another AST and skip over the unwanted nodes in the resulted 'clone'? I mean, the original AST is meant to represent your parsing result exactly; sure, you are free to *translate* this AST into whatever structure you like, including another AST with branches chopped off, but *the original one should still reflect what you actually parsed from your file*.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi:  So when modify the value of a variable x by adding one to it, do you always keep the original value of x around?  Generally not.  You only keep the original around if you need it.   Likewise with modifying a tree.    I suspect OP already understands this.   His question is how to modify the tree.

Comment: @IraBaxter While you may be right in the general sense, it is not so when it comes to the philosophy of ANTLR (I'll look for the relevant quotation). The power of Abstract Syntax Trees come from the fact they are visit-able and *translatable* according to the needs, but it will be a pain to *transform* them - therefore I doubt there actually exists a (non-hackish) answer to his question.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi it's true that I can translate the tree to desired form. But before that I would like to delete a sub tree since I Feel it's easy to manipulate the AST

Comment: @ssdimmanuel " I Feel it's easy to manipulate the AST" Ok, maybe I'm wrong and you can easily manipulate the AST, it has been ages since I last played with ANTRL. Good luck. If you are wrong, you know what to do: a  visitor that just repeats the AST except the one subtree you want skipped; how hard can it be?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: ANTLR philopsopy ==> "power of ASTs.. translatable... pain to transform them".   Wow; Terrence Parr actually said this???  Well, things are only a pain when you have poor tools.  (Hey, making integrated circuits is a pain.  Guess I'll stick with relays and wires).   You can have better tools based on the philosophy that a) you should build them instead of whining, and b) they should be convenient to use.  See "non-hackish" solution that implements AST transforms directly and even avoids manually crawling over trees: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html

Comment: @IraBaxter Note: that was my interpretation. However, [looky here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~admin/2012/12/08/Tree+rewriting+in+ANTLR+v4) "Because most ANTLR users don't build compilers, I decided to focus on the other applications for ANTLR v4: parsing and extracting information and then **translations**. ... "Users of ANTLR v4 don't have to learn AST construction syntax or AST tree grammar syntax and semantics." ... Happy reading.

Comment: @IraBaxter DMS: what?  Domain specific languages? Oberon? You beardy geeky guy, what times do you think we live in? Everything needs to be done yesterday, all the products need to last at most a year (until we get the next version to the market... planned obsolescence is a feature for our bottom lime), the attention span of today's generation is exactly 140 characters long, emoticons included;making integrated circuits is for the People's Republic of China, not for us. We are "an advanced service economy", you know... 100 hairdressers in a circle tending the hair of the one in front (grin)

Comment: @IraBaxter (thanks for the DMS reference).